# Optimize MYSQL subqueries

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to optimize this query?

I know it is getting held up in the subqueries:

```
    (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') FROM storeCheckRecords
    WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000032)
```

Without the IFNULL subquery it executes in less than 1 sec.  This example takes 20 secs with the subquerys and is only 54 rows.  Anyway to rewrite this to speed it up?  Thanks for any and all help.

```
SELECT 
   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS @storeid:=z.id
  ,z.biz_name
  ,z.wf_store_name
  ,z.e_address
  ,z.e_city
  ,z.e_state 
  ,z.e_postal
  ,IFNULL(total_sales - prev_total_sales,'CV') as diff_total_sales
  ,IFNULL(d_source,'N/A') as d_source
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales1 - prev_unit_sales1 , (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                            FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                            WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000032)
   ) as diff_unit_sales1
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales2 - prev_unit_sales2, (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                           FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                           WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000033)
   ) as diff_unit_sales2
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales3 - prev_unit_sales3, (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                           FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                           WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000034)
   ) as diff_unit_sales3
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales4 - prev_unit_sales4, (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                           FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                           WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000035)
   ) as diff_unit_sales4
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales5 - prev_unit_sales5, (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                           FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                           WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000036)
   ) as diff_unit_sales5
  ,IFNULL(unit_sales6 - prev_unit_sales6, (SELECT IFNULL(max(datetimesql),'NS') 
                                           FROM storeCheckRecords 
                                           WHERE store_id=@storeid AND upc=855555000038)
   ) as diff_unit_sales6 
FROM  
   (SELECT  s1.id,s1.biz_name as biz_name 
           ,s1.wf_store_name as wf_store_name
           ,s1.e_address as e_address
           ,s1.e_city as e_city
           ,s1.e_state as e_state
           ,s1.e_postal as e_postal
           ,sum(s2.unit_sales) as total_sales
           ,sum(s2.unit_sales/4.28571428571) as week_avg
           ,group_concat(DISTINCT s2.d_source separator ',') as d_source
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 1 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales1
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 2 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales2
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales3
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 4 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales4
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 5 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales5
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 6 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE NULL END) AS unit_sales6
    FROM allStores as s1
    INNER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2
      ON    s1.id = s2.store_id
        AND s2.datetimesql BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31'
        AND s1.key_retailer LIKE 'WHOLE FOODS' 
        AND s1.wf_region LIKE 'Midwest' 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  1 AS id
                       ,'855555000032' AS upc 
                UNION 
                SELECT  2
                       ,'855555000033' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  3
                       ,'855555000034' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  4
                       ,'855555000035' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  5
                       ,'855555000036' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  6
                       ,'855555000038') u 
      ON u.upc = s2.upc  
    GROUP BY s1.id) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT  s1.id,s1.biz_name as prev_biz_name
           ,s1.wf_store_name as prev_wf_store_name
           ,s1.e_address as prev_e_address
           ,s1.e_city as prev_e_city
           ,s1.e_state as prev_e_state
           ,s1.e_postal as prev_e_postal
           ,sum(s2.unit_sales) as prev_total_sales
           ,sum(s2.unit_sales/4.28571428571) as prev_week_avg
           ,group_concat(DISTINCT s2.d_source separator ',') as prev_d_source
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 1 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales1
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 2 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales2
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales3
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 4 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales4
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 5 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales5
           ,SUM(CASE u.id WHEN 6 THEN s2.unit_sales ELSE 0 END) AS prev_unit_sales6
    FROM allStores as s1
    INNER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2
      ON    s1.id = s2.store_id
        AND s2.datetimesql BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30'
        AND s1.key_retailer LIKE 'WHOLE FOODS' 
        AND s1.wf_region LIKE 'Midwest'
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  1 AS id
                       ,'855555000032' AS upc 
                UNION 
                SELECT  2
                       ,'855555000033' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  3
                       ,'855555000034' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  4
                       ,'855555000035' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  5
                       ,'855555000036' 
                UNION 
                SELECT  6
                       ,'855555000038') u 
      ON u.upc = s2.upc  
    GROUP BY s1.id) y
ON x.id = y.id
RIGHT JOIN
   (SELECT  s1.id
           ,s1.biz_name
           ,s1.wf_store_name
           ,s1.e_address
           ,s1.e_city
           ,s1.e_state
           ,s1.e_postal
    FROM allStores as s1
    WHERE     1 
          AND s1.key_retailer LIKE 'WHOLE FOODS' 
          AND s1.wf_region LIKE 'Midwest') z
ON y.id = z.id
ORDER BY wf_store_name ASC
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Thank you Henry.  I indexed upc, store_id, and datetimsql.  This cut it in half, but I want to get it down further.  Here is the explain and I am trying to get everything done in sql because I feeding the result to datatables.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived22> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    54  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived8>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   
1   PRIMARY <derived15> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   
22  DERIVED s1  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    64121   Using where
15  DERIVED <derived16> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   Using temporary; Using filesort
15  DERIVED s2  ref upc,store_id,upc_2,store_id_2,datetimesql,datetime...   upc 47  u.upc   2159    Using where
15  DERIVED s1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   dpalame_foodiecpg.s2.store_id   1   Using where
16  DERIVED NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
17  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
18  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
19  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
20  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
21  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union16,17,18,19,20,21>    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
8   DERIVED <derived9>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   Using temporary; Using filesort
8   DERIVED s2  range   upc,store_id,upc_2,store_id_2,datetimesql,datetime...   datetimesql 3   NULL    1810    Using where; Using join buffer
8   DERIVED s1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   dpalame_foodiecpg.s2.store_id   1   Using where
9   DERIVED NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
10  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
11  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
12  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
13  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
14  UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union9,10,11,12,13,14> ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
7   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
6   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
5   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
4   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
3   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
2   UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY    storeCheckRecords   index   upc,upc_2   datetimesql_3   53  NULL    60452   Using where; Using index
```

Comment: i guess bringing that horizontal scroll bar over could help. who wants the edit ?

Comment: For just the right type of question http://sqlformat.org/

Comment: thx Mihai, helped somewhat. then again maybe a Revert is better :>  Then I brought it into Sublime and was horrified

Comment: I`m guessing that python parser doenst know mysql too well

Comment: good to know about tho

Comment: I have never seen such a complicated query, it's scary. It seems that you try to do all the work with SQL. Why don't write simpler queries to retrieve the data you need and then do the computation with the programming language you are using ? Instead of optimizing you should simplify. And I bet it will be much more efficient.

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), in particular code blocks for queries and their output. Select & press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1):

first try using mysql built in query analyzer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html

```
 explain [your_query]
```

and come back with the result.
my guess is this part of the query

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT  1 AS id
                   ,'855555000032' AS upc 
            UNION 
            SELECT  2
                   ,'855555000033' 
            UNION 
            SELECT  3
                   ,'855555000034' 
            UNION 
            SELECT  4
                   ,'855555000035' 
            UNION 
            SELECT  5
                   ,'855555000036' 
            UNION 
            SELECT  6
                   ,'855555000038') u
```

if this sub query is static, then it should by better to create as a myisam table , and create index for column id, and column upc

the way your query work, will utilize alot of temporary table. 
for each subquery , mysql will create a temporary table. 
performance will be degraded if the result from the query is big enough.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

you might redesign your query into separate views

also, slow query can be caused by unindex parameter column (column used in where queries)

a handy recipe for performance is to create a set column(s) index for each "where" parameter on queries used against table, a set column(s) index for each "order"

try to see if "storeId" and "upc" column in table "storeCheckRecords" is already indexed as a set.

also see if you have "innodb_file_per_table =1" set in your mysql config.
separate tablespace have positive impact on performance where big table data involved.
but, if the innodb_file_per_table is set to 0 before, you need to recreate the whole database.

Comment: Thank you Henry.  I indexed upc, store_id, and datetimsql.  This cut it in half, but I want to get it down further.  Here is the explain and I am trying to get everything done in sql because I feeding the result to datatables.

Comment: what does the mysql query analyzer said about your query?

Comment: I added it to the question because it was quite long.

Comment: Sorry for my bad etiquette don't post a lot.  Fixed it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: From the sql analyzer , the subqueries on table storecheckrecords process 60.452 records 6 times. That is where most all you processing time goes. I'm on mobile right now, so i cannot write query with proper formating. But you could optimize the query of storecheckrecords by combine them into a single subquery. Select storeid, upc, max(datetimesql) from storecheckrecord group by storeid, upc where storeid=@storeid and upc in [insert_your_upc_in array_style]  . Then join this with your query.